# Unique constraints cause error when duplicating record in Odoo 11

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I have an unique constraint for my `code` field. When I click on the 'duplicate' option in the dropdown action I'm getting the validate error.
Is there any way to use 'duplicate' even if the field `code` is unique?

```
 class sample(models.Model):
    _name = 'sample'

    code=fields.Char('Code',required=True)
    name=fields.Char('Name',required=True)

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('code_uniq', 'unique (code)', 'The code must be unique !')
    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. You have two ways to do this. When you duplicate a record, `copy` method is called, and it creates a new record with the values of the original record (it only copies the values of the fields whose argument `copy=True` -by default is *True*-). So you can change that argument in the `code` field declaration, or modify the `copy` method to avoid the identical replication.

**Way 1: modifying the *copy* argument of the *code* field**

This way would be the easiest one, but it will give you an error if `code` field is required.

```
class sample(models.Model):
    _name = 'sample'

    code = fields.Char('Code', required=False, copy=False)
    name = fields.Char('Name', required=True)

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('code_uniq', 'unique (code)', 'The code must be unique !')
    ]
```

**Way 2: modifying the *copy* method of the model *sample***

This is the way you're looking for if `code` must be required.

```
class sample(models.Model):
    _name = 'sample'

    code = fields.Char('Code', required=True)
    name = fields.Char('Name', required=True)

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('code_uniq', 'unique (code)', 'The code must be unique !')
    ]

    @api.one
    def copy(self, default=None):
        if default is None:
            default = {}
        new_code = (self.code + ' (copy)') if self.code else ''
        default.update({
            'code': new_code,
        })
        new_sample = super(sample, self).copy(default=default)
        return new_sample
```

Comment: I'm facing this error when i used way 2                                                    @api.returns('self', lambda value: value.id)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: I have tried way 1                                                                      ERROR: null value in column "code" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (42, null, Cold ,1, 2018-04-06 05:07:34.181, 1, 2018-04-06 05:07:34.181)

Comment: @VarshaBolli The error in **Way 1** makes sense, because when you duplicate the record, `code` is not copied to the new record, and it remains null, and as it's required, it gives you an error. It would be OK if `code` wasn't required, I'll specify that in the answer, but **Way 2** works for sure.